# Pie Chart with Labels and facet in altair: not able to proper render the value labels

Tags: altair

Using the [single chart example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/pie_chart.html), I have a label for each piece of cake.

[image]

If I try to transform it in a faceted chart using this code

```py
df=pd.read_csv("input.csv",keep_default_na=False)

base=alt.Chart(df).encode(
    theta=alt.Theta(field="v", type="quantitative"),
    color=alt.Color(field="k", type="nominal")
)


pie = base.mark_arc(outerRadius=100)
text = base.mark_text(radius=115,fill= "black").encode(alt.Text(field="v", type="quantitative", format=",.1f"))

alt.layer(pie, text, data=df).facet(column='label')
```

all the labels are all in the same wedge and then illegible (here the vega lite version [vega lite version](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-2I0jEwoqjUWBHVJCAA)).

[image]

how to have a result similar to that of the single chart?

Thank you

```
f,n,k,v,label
1,3,0-5 %,99.7289972899729,Forest
1,4,5-10 %,0.27100271002710025,Forest
0,1,0-5 %,100.0,Non-Forest
254,5,0-5 %,99.0077177508269,unclassifiable
254,6,5-10 %,0.9922822491730982,unclassifiable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must add:

- `stack=True` as channel encoding option in the `theta` channel encoding;
- and `.resolve_scale( theta="independent" )` to the chart.

And it works (I learned this thanks [to Mattijn van Hoek](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/discussions/2887#discussioncomment-4971355)).

```
df=pd.read_csv("input.csv",keep_default_na=False)

base=alt.Chart(df).encode(
    theta=alt.Theta(field="v", type="quantitative", stack=True),
    color=alt.Color(field="k", type="nominal")
)


pie = base.mark_arc(outerRadius=100)
text = base.mark_text(radius=115,fill= "black").encode(alt.Text(field="v", type="quantitative", format=",.1f"))

alt.layer(pie, text, data=df).facet(column='label').resolve_scale(theta="independent")
```